# Bijective Lie group homomorphisms are isomorphisms

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups

I have searched in MES and haven't found an answer to this following problem. Consider a Lie group homomorphism $f:G\rightarrow H$ (i.e. a differentiable map which is also a group homomorphism) and assume $f$ is bijective. Then $f$ is a Lie group isomorphism (i.e. $f^{-1}$ is a Lie group homomorphism as defined previously).

I would like to prove this without resorting to the exponential map if possible.

Since $f$ is a bijective group homomorphism, $\exists f^{-1}$ which is again a group homomorphism. I would only need to prove that it is differentiable, and the most straightforward method I can think of would be the use of the inverse function theorem.
It would suffice to show that the differential map $f_{*p}:T_pG \rightarrow T_{f(p)}H$ is a linear isomorphism, but I am struggling trying to see how this is implied by the bijectivity assumption.

Is there something obvious that I am not seeing?

Answer (score 2):

Well, there is a theorem that says all homomorphism between Lie groups $G$ and $H$ have constant rank (which you can prove either by constructing smooth group actions or by playing with the left multiplication, which is a diffeomorphism for a fixed $g\in G$), and you know it's a bijection, so by applying a rank theorem on smooth bijective function with constant rank, you see it's a diffeomorphism. The inverse of a bijective group morphism is a morphism, thus everything is alright !

Answer (score 1):

This may sound a bit strange, but as far as I can see, you have to first prove that $\dim(G)\geq\dim(H)$, say by invoking Sard's theorem. Then you can use the fact that the kernel of $f_{*e}$ coincides with the Lie algebra of the Kernel of $f$. Hence injectivity of $f$ implies injectivity of $f_{*e}$, which in turn shows that $\dim(G)=\dim(H)$ and hence bijectivity of $f_{*e}$. Using left translations, this easily implies bijectivity of $f_{*p}$ for any $p\in G$.

To indicate that the consideration of dimension is indeed necessary, observe that the result is not true if you allow your groups to be non-paracompact. Indeed you can consider the product of the Lie group $\mathbb R$ with the discrete group $\mathbb R$ and the obvious homomorphism to $\mathbb R^2$, which is smooth and bijective but not an isomorphism. (So allowing uncountably many separable connected components is already enough to make the result fail.)